# How to get font folder path in Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, fonts, directory

In Windows O.S i can get the fonts folder path  using this java code :

```
System.out.println( FontManager.getFontPath( true ) );  // C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
```

But in Mac OS X this code returns nothing. Is there an alternative code for this in Mac ?

Answer (score 21):

There are two paths for fonts on Mac OS X (that I know of), `/Library/Fonts` and `/System/Library/Fonts`.

If you're just looking for a list of fonts, you can use:

```
java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts()
```

A bit heavy handed, since it creates a `GraphicsEnvironment` object, but it will return an array of `java.awt.Font` containing an object that represents each font available on the system.

Comment: another path is $HOME/Library/Fonts - for every user.

Comment: @jomo666: Didn't know about that, thanks. Had to check for curiosity, and found it non-empty. Now I have to figure out where "Brush Script" came from...

Comment: @Nathan ... Thanks a lot. What i actually want is if i have a font name, say "Arial" i want to get its font file, and read it as a normal File. So i must get the font file path on Mac to read it as a normal file.

Comment: @Nathan: It's not just the fonts. Every directory hierarchy can be placed in three positions, `/System/Library/***`, `/Library/***` and `~/Library/***`, to represent things belonging to the OS, the machine, and the user. Most of the system APIs, when asked to look for something, automatically look for things in all these, with the order `~/`, `/` and then `/System`.

Comment: @Yuji: Thanks greatly for the info, was not aware of that precise of structure.

Comment: So guys ... Any suggestions ?

Comment: 'Fraid not, other than checking the paths identified in the correct order. You can get the user directory from the system properties.

Comment: @Nathan ... Hmmm, i will try that to see what will i get.

Comment: According to http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2435 there are five locations, although only four of them are considered current.

Comment: Heads up: In Catalina, there is now also `/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental`.